# block facebook app in WiFi system

Tags: call-screening, facebook

Honestly, I want for my kids not to use facebook.
But, they still use facebook app on the wifi network.

I successfully blocked facebook domain with the router management on my home wifi network.
So, this facebook website was blocked in windows system, and other android system.
But, facebook app still access to the facebook website(?).

How to block facebook app? 
I cannot find domain address using facebook app.

Comment: Usually the apps use a different server that the web page. There are a large number of apps that can monitor the network traffic of apps, for example [Net Monitor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.secuso.privacyfriendlynetmonitorapp)

Comment: Install a firewall such as [Netguard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.faircode.netguard) on the phone and block Facebook app when wifi is on.